# JavascriptExecutor Set Attribute function updates in DOM but not in GUI

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

```html
<div class="" id="searchWidgetNew"><div class="errMsg width100 fl" id="gerr"></div><div class="" id="searchWidgetCommon"><div><div class="dF justifyBetween flexWrap"><div class="col-md-11 pad0 dF width90 flexWrap justifyCenter"><div class="col-md-12 pad0 dF flexWrap brdrRd5 marginB10  fltHpySrchWrp whiteBg"><div class="dF whiteBg col-md-3 col-sm-5 alignItemsCenter brdrTpBtmLft width23"><i class="blueGrey padR5 ico18 hypflt-from "></i><input type="text" id="gosuggest_inputSrc" class="inputSrch" placeholder="From" value="" autocomplete="new-password" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="react-autosuggest-1" aria-expanded="false"></div><!-- react-text: 165 --><!-- /react-text --><div class="dF whiteBg borderRight alignItemsCenter "></div><div class="dF whiteBg col-md-3 col-sm-5 alignItemsCenter  padL20 width23"><i class="blueGrey padR5 ico18 hypflt-destination "></i><i class="hypflt-swp fltHpySwp posAbs  ico24 blueLt curPointFlt"></i><input type="text" id="gosuggest_inputDest" class="inputSrch" placeholder="Destination" value="" autocomplete="new-password" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="react-autosuggest-1" aria-expanded="false"></div><div class="dF whiteBg borderRight alignItemsCenter"></div><div class="dF whiteBg col-sm-5 alignItemsCenter  col-md-2 "><i class="hypflt-calendar blueGrey padR5 ico20"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Departure" readonly="" class="inputSrch curPointFlt " value=""><!-- react-text: 175 --><!-- /react-text --></div><div class="dF whiteBg borderRight alignItemsCenter"></div><div class="dF whiteBg col-md-2 col-sm-5 alignItemsCenter"><i class="hypflt-calendar blueGrey padR5 ico20"></i><input type="text" placeholder="Return" readonly="" class="inputSrch curPointFlt " value=""><!-- react-text: 180 --><!-- /react-text --><input type="hidden" id="gi_return_date" name="gi_return_date" value=""></div><div class="dF whiteBg borderRight alignItemsCenter"></div><div class="dF whiteBg fl col-sm-5 justifyBetween ht45 alignItemsCenter brdrTpBtmRt curPointFlt width20" id="pax_link_common"><span class="dF alignItemsCenter ico14 textOverflow blueGrey"><i class="hypflt-adult blueGrey padR5 ico18"></i><span id="pax_label" class="blueGrey textOverflow">1 Traveller, </span><!-- react-text: 187 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text --><span class="blueGrey textOverflow"> Economy</span></span><div class="paxMobile paxContainer dn"><div class="errMsg width100 fl dn"><span class="alert_msg failure_msg fl"><b class="status_info fl">ERROR: </b><span class="status_cont"></span></span></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="pax_close" class="icon-cancel-circle fr marginT10 marginR10 fr greyDr mobdn"></a><ul><li class="roomRow dF justifyBetween"><div class="widgetUserBlock fl"><label class="ico14 db padB5"><span>Adults</span><small class="font12Lt db padT3"> (12+ yrs)</small></label><div class="number-spinner number-spinnerFil"><button class="fl minSpin brdrTpBtmLft" id="adultPaxMinus" data-dir="dwn">−</button><input type="text" id="adultPaxBox" class="fl numbSpin" value="1"><button class="fl plusSpin brdrTpBtmRt" id="adultPaxPlus" data-dir="up">+</button></div></div><div class="widgetUserBlock fl"><label class="ico14 db padB5"><span>Children</span><small class="font12Lt db padT3"> (2-12 yrs)</small></label><div class="number-spinner"><button class="fl minSpin brdrTpBtmLft" id="childPaxMinus" data-dir="dwn">−</button><input type="text" id="childPaxBox" class="fl numbSpin" value="0"><button class="fl plusSpin brdrTpBtmRt" id="childPaxPlus" data-dir="up">+</button></div></div><div class="widgetUserBlock fl"><label class="ico14 db padB5"><span>Infant(s)</span><small class="font12Lt db padT3"> (below 2 yrs)</small></label><div class="number-spinner"><button class="fl minSpin brdrTpBtmLft" id="infantPaxMinus" data-dir="dwn">−</button><input type="text" id="infantPaxBox" class="fl numbSpin" value="0"><button class="fl plusSpin brdrTpBtmRt" id="infantPaxPlus" data-dir="up">+</button></div></div></li><li class="roomRow dF justifyBetween alignItemsCenter"><span class=" ico15 width40">Travel Class</span><div class="posRel dIF width90 alignItemsCenter"><div class="width100 "><label><!-- react-text: 226 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 227 --><!-- /react-text --></label><div><select class="custSelect width100 whiteBg padTB5 padLR10" id="gi_class"><option value="E">Economy</option><option value="B">Business</option><option value="F">First class</option><option value="W">Premium Economy</option></select></div></div><i class="hypflt-dropDown ico8 slectArr"></i></div></li></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="justifyCenter col-md-1 col-sm-12 dF padLR0"><button class="fb button orange large ht45 fltHpySrchBtn" value="Search" type="submit" id="gi_search_btn">SEARCH</button></div></div><div class="dF width100"></div></div><div class="dF alignItemsCenter white padTB20 ico13 width100" style="transition: margin 500ms ease 0s;"><div class="dF"><span class="fltHmFltr curPointFlt " id="nonStop">Non-Stop</span><span class="fltHmFltr curPointFlt " id="student_fare_check"> Student Fare</span></div><div class="hypFltErr"><span class="alert_msg failure_msg dF brdrRd5"><b class="status_info fl">ERROR: </b><span class="status_cont red ico13">Please enter a valid Source</span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

I am trying to automate search functionality in Goibobo web.  For Departure we need to select a date.  I used Javascript Executor Set Attribute for this.  Value of Attribute is updated in DOM using Set Attribute, but GUI is not updated with the updated Value. So when I click on Search, it says, please select a departure date.  Can anyone help me in this.

Here is the code I have show far - `

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']")).sendKeys("Madurai (IXM)");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);



    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputDest']")).sendKeys("Chennai (MAA)");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputDest']")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputDest']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement when = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder ='Departure']"));

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    System.out.println("running javascript");
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','Tue, 2 Jul')", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder ='Departure']")));
    //js.executeAsyncScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','Tue, 2 Jul')", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder ='Departure']")));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("ran");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Search']")).click();
    System.out.println("clicked on search");`
```

Comment: Why do you need a JavaScript executor to update the value?  If it's a text field you should be able to simply use WebElement.sendKeys("whatever date you want");

or, WebElement.setValue("whatever date you want");

perhaps uploading the HTML for the page you are testing would be useful.

Comment: Hello, Peck.  It is not a Text field actually.  We need to pick a date using the calendar it shows, when we try Manually. So,  trying to achieve this using JavaScriptExecutor.     Will upload the html in some time.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the website the Departure field actually does have an input type of text:

    <input type="text" placeholder="Departure" readonly="" class="inputSrch 
    curPointFlt " value="">

Comment: ok.. I tried the sendKeys as well, but it is not typing them.  Can you please try from your end as well?  The website is https://www.goibibo.com .  Also, Yes, the Test Case fails, without giving ARROW_DOWN and ENTER.  It wants you to select from the dropdown list.  Otherwise, when you click on Search, the one we actually entered in From and To, will go off.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: I am getting the same results as you and I'm not sure how to fix it, except if you were to "manually" use Selenium to click through the calendar to the date that you want and click that date, which does look possible although extremely messy.  It sort of depends on what you want to use this script for if you want to go that route.

Comment: That is right Peck, I agree.  Iterating through dates is still possible as you told, but extremely tough.  Anyways thanks for giving a try.  Let me know if you are able to fix a same kind of scenario(Attribute value is updated in DOM but not GUI) in somewhere.  Also, let me know if you can help me like "Is generally GUI updated once we use JavascriptExecutor SetAttribute?"

Comment: Generally setAttribute updates the UI.  I've used that exact syntax to set the value of elements in the UI.  I can't say for sure why it isn't working, but the dropdown on that field is likely involved in the answer.

WebElement.setValue() does the exact same thing as js.JavascriptExecutor(arguments[0].setAttribute('value'....


in my experience and the calendar is the only thing different than fields I've used.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Peck, can you upvote my question so that it will be visible to more users? Still I am yet to figure out answer for the question.